# HTML tag <s> is not shown on /questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Yesterday I used the `<s>` tag in the body of a question, see [here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/when-am-i-allowed-to-leave-out-the-definite-article-in-front-of-a-possessive).

> [image: strikethrough]

When you look at it everything seems to be formatted well. However, when you go to the [/questions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions) overview, scroll down to the above mentioned question and take a look at the first two lines of the text, you can see that the html tag is ignored.

> [image: no strikethrough]

I am using Ubuntu with firefox 40.0.3

Comment: Says Kevin Montrose: "We strip out html tags when building a post's summary" http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155817/209360